# Python FastAPI: Having a superclass model .dict() also include the subclass keys

Tags: python, fastapi

Using FastAPI for Python 3.7+ I have the following BaseDocument class:

```
class BaseDocument(BaseModel):
    name: str
    category: str
    description = "Base Document"
    type: str

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "name": "stack_instance_document_example",
                "description":
                "an example of a document, using the stack_instance type",
                "example_field": "Random",
                "category": "items",
                "type": "example_document"
            }
        }
```

And a subclassing model:

```
class ExampleModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    type = "example_document"
    category = "items"
    "example_field": str
```

Now, if I do an API call for a put using the class_config schema extra example, where I am expecting a BaseDocument and I use .dict() on that BaseDocument, the resulting dict does NOT include the "example_field" key.

For instance,

```
@router.put('')
def put_document(document: BaseDocument):
    """Update (or create) the document with a specific type and an optional name given in the payload"""
    logger.info(f"[PutDocument] API PUT request with data: {BaseDocument}")

    task = DocumentTask({
        'channel': 'worker',
        'document': document.dict(),
        'subtype': "PUT_DOCUMENT"
    })
    ....
```

The document.dict() in my logs only has the fields of the BaseDocument. Anyway to get a dict representation of the complete document?

Comment: You're telling the function that the payload contains a `BaseDocument`, so that's what you'll get back. You can't also get back the `example_field`. If you want this, you'll have to: make `ExampleModel` inherit from `BaseDocument` (at the moment it's inheriting from `BaseModel`), and then change the FastAPI function to expect an `ExampleModel` instead.

Comment: Problem is, I have other models except ExampleModel and what I want to do is create a generic 'document model retrieval api'.

So that for instance I can  PUT both an ExampleModel2 with field example_field2 and a ExampleModel1 with field example_field1 if they are subclasses of the BaseDocument

Comment: You might want to try setting the parameter to be `Union[ExampleModel1, ExampleModel2]`. I'm not sure if FastAPI will like it, but it seems like a reasonable attempt! Remember to `from typing import Union` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the comments works but unfortunately will cause the lack of a pre-filled in generic example.
The best solution I've found for my use case is by using the Request directly and looking at the JSON body (see https://www.starlette.io/requests/) - which includes all the key/values while keeping the pre-filled in example for the FastAPI